# How to add definiton to cmake using command line?

Tags: c++, cmake, torch, torchvision

I build torchvision from source and during install phase I get compilation errors and to resolve that, I need to add

```
add_definitions(-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__)
add_definitions(-D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__)
add_definitions(-D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__)
```

lines to CMakeLists.txt. I don't want to edit CMakeLists.txt to automate the building process and I just want to add definitions using command line. I searched it but got no luck.

I tried adding

```
-D__CUDA_NO_HALF_CONVERSIONS__=ON \
-D__CUDA_NO_BFLOAT16_CONVERSIONS__=ON |
-D__CUDA_NO_HALF2_OPERATORS__=ON
```

but it didn't work.